# Apache mod_rewrite redirect any request on domain name to another domain

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

How can I use mod_rewrite on Apache to direct any request for any page in a particular VirtualHost to another domain? i.e. something like:

```
<VirtualHost whatever.com:80>
Redirect * to http://www.some-other-domain.com/some-page.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.some-other-domain.com/some-page.html [R=301,L]
```

You may want to read [this article](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/) for more information.